# Idea of a basic LoopingSelector in CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css, loopingselector

I'm a programmer who is no skills at design. I know Basic CSS3 but i'm better in JavaScript.

My question is I need to do a basic LoopingSelector.

[image]

Basic idea is there is a selected value on middle of screen and up and down value is increasing and decreasing. May be I can do that in JavaScript but there is will be performance issue and responsive issue I think. So I want to do it with CSS. I have problem with the selectors right know. I have no clue how to be. So I need a guide about it if somebody can help me.

Thanks.

Edit:

CSS

```
    .vote {
        list-style: none;
    }

        .vote li {
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .vote .selected {
            display: inline;
        }

        /*It must show 2 items after the selected class */
        .vote li.selected:nth-child(n + 2) {
            display: inline;
        }

        /*It must show 2 items before the selected class */
        .vote li.selected:nth-child(-n + 2) {
            display: inline;
        }
```

Html

```
<ul class="vote">

    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li class="selected">5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: please include your code, and narrow down the question.

Comment: @Tomalak No I didn't. My first opinion is CSS. If i can't do that with CSS. There is only left JavaScript opinion.

Comment: @Tomalak It is not the point of the question. Ok may be you are right but If I can do that with CSS why should I do with JS. I just want to know, Is it possible with CSS ? If it is possible then how.

Comment: @Tomalak I edited it okay ? So do you have solution about the question ?

Comment: Not Possible With CSS

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `nth-child` here because n is not the current element. Its a counter which counts from 0 to N. So when you write `nth-child(3n)` every third child gets the style applied.

However for you problem you could use `selector1 + selector2` to style elements which are siblings after `selector1`. But you cant access elements before

```
li.selected + li + li{
    /* 2 li later */
}
```

Comment: No, you can not select siblings before the element. Have you tested your solution ?

Comment: I tried it now, and Uploaded to jsfiddle as @vals say siblings have a problem. http://jsfiddle.net/lyzerk/r09579dz/

Comment: You are right - not working. Well - then the answer is: no - not possible